# Why an online equation editor cannot be used to produce matrices in LYX?

Tags: lyx

I've started using LyX just a couple of months ago. As a beginner sometimes I use the graphic method (cmd+m), while other times I try to write TEX code by myself (cmd+L). Lately, I've discovered a web-site which generates LaTeX code (http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-us), generally it works well if inserted in LyX, but I've discovered that it doesn't work for matrices. For example: to produce a matrix here on stackexchange.com I use the following code (generated from the web-site):

```
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
```

while if I insert the above code in LyX it gives me lots of errors codes. Is there any way to make the above lines work also in LyX?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: bmatrix is defined by the amsmath package have you loaded that?

Comment: Have you `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely a beginner...LOL. Thank you very much for your help David and Astrinus, problem solved!

Comment: You should be able to go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste From LaTeX in LyX 2.1.x. If that doesn't work, please open a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, you need the `amsmath` package to use `bmatrix` and similar environments. LyX does not add this automatically unless you actually use some of its features via the GUI in LyX. If you haven't done that, there are two options available:

1. Document --> Settings --> Math options. Select *Always load* for `amsmath`.
2. Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. Add `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Only do one of these, or you'll load `amsmath` twice, which isn't really necessary.